# how to create product references of In app purchase?

Tags: iphone

if i want to test in app purchase, how can i create product references in ITune connect?
it force me to select some application in my iTune connect, 
or i want to create dummy App on iTune connect?
could you please tell me step by step to create product references for test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fill in the details of the application that you are going to use the In-App purchases with. You can upload the binary at a later date.
The application's bundle ID needs to be the same as the one you're using to test the In-App purchases.

Comment: did you mean Application ID ?
eg, com.sample.myapp

Comment: Yes, that's known as the Application's Bundle Identifier.